# Osculating Plane of $(t,t^2,t^3)$ and a result

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

> Find the osculating plane of curve parametric form $(t,t^2,t^3)$. Also prove that intersection of three osculating planes on any three points of curve lies on plane containing those three points .

My attempt ::

I solved first part of question and found equation of osculating on a point on curve whose parameter is t

$$3t^2X-3tY+Z-t^3=0$$

Now second part of question is where I am stuck . My thoughts are let three points on curve be whose parameter are a,b and c. Then write equation for their osculating plane ,Find intersection point and  find equation of plane containing three points . And finally satisfie the intersection point in plane .

This process seems quite lengthy . Is there a smart way to do it ?

Comment: https://journals.iupui.edu/index.php/ias/article/download/14115/14186/0

Comment: @bubba sir this article confuses more i  couldn't quite follow what author wanted to say .

Comment: I manged to solve the last part by finding intersection point using Cramer rule and putting them in plane matrix . Took some time but could do it . Now only I wonder if there is some nice trick to avoid these calculations .

Comment: I think if They aren't parallel they will intersect . Intersection of two planes is line and line will intersect another plane on a point . I went through computational nightmare but intersection comes out to be sweet $$(\frac{a+b+c}{3},\frac{ab+bc+ac}{3},abc)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some fairly obscure theory that you could use to shorten your work. Given a polynomial $f$ of degree $n$, there is a unique symmetric multi-affine function $F$ of $n$ variables such that $F(t,t,\ldots, t) = f(t)$ for all $t$. The function $F$ is called the **[polar form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form)** or the **[blossom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_(functional))** of $f$. This concept is well-known among people who work with Bezier curves, and also in classical algebraic geometry. More info [here](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-RR-34.pdf).

Some examples of blossoms are:
$$f(t) = t \Longrightarrow F(u,v,w) = \tfrac13(u+v+w)$$
$$f(t) = t^2 \Longrightarrow F(u,v,w) = \tfrac13(vw + wu + uv)$$
$$f(t) = (1-t)^3 \Longrightarrow F(u,v,w) = (1-u)(1-v)(1-w)$$

In particular, the polar form of your cubic curve is
$$
F(u,v,w) = \Bigl(\; \tfrac13(u+v+w),\;
 \tfrac13(vw + wu + uv),\; uvw \;\Bigr)
$$
Polar forms have some nice geometric properties.

For example, for a parametric quadratic curve, the polar form $F(u,v)$ gives the intersection point of the tangents at the parameter values $u$ and $v$.

Similarly, for a non-planar parametric cubic curve, **the polar form $F(u,v, w)$ gives the intersection point of the osculating planes at the parameter values $u$, $v$, and $w$**. I see that you already rediscovered this for yourself (after a lot of algebra, I would guess). To be honest, I can't remember where I learned this, and I can't find a proof.

To show that the four points are coplanar, you can look at the determinant
$$\left|\matrix{
\tfrac13(u+v+w) & \tfrac13(vw + wu + uv) & uvw & 1 \\
u & u^2 & u^3 & 1 \\
v & v^2 & v^3 & 1 \\
w & w^2 & w^3 & 1
}\right|
$$
This determinant gives the [volume of the tetrahedron](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetrahedron.html) defined by the four points, so it is zero precisely when the four points are coplanar. There is probably some clever way to show that the determinant is zero, but I don't see it, right now. I expect that it's easy to show by brute-force algebra or by using a system like Mathematica.

Alternatively (and much better, I think) …
Let $P(u)$, $P(v)$, and $P(w)$ be the three points on the curve. Then a formula on page 16 of [Ramshaw’s document](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-RR-34.pdf) says that
$$
F(u,v,w) = \frac{(w-v)^2}{3(w-u)(u-v)}P(u) +
           \frac{(w-u)^2}{3(w-v)(v-u)}P(v) +
           \frac{(v-u)^2}{3(v-w)(w-u)}P(w)
$$
It’s straightforward to show that the three coefficients in this formula add up to 1. So, the formula says that **the intersection point $F(u,v,w)$ is an affine combination of the the three curve points, and therefore lies in the plane containing them**.

Note that this last formula is valid for **any** parametric cubic curve, not just the very simple one that you’re considering. Pretty neat, huh. We can thank Monsieur de Casteljau for this.

Comment: I’ve been a fan of blossoming ever since Ramshaw re-invented it. So, I knew about this document even back in the 1980s. It took me a couple of days to realize that it neatly answers the OP’s question.

Comment: "For example, for a parametric quadratic curve, the polar form F(u,v) gives the intersection point of the tangents at the parameter values u and v." could you elaborate on this? Heck, I find this really fascinating, could you maybe make a separate  MSE post where you write more details about what is in this document. Some of the terminology there is much difficult to understand compared to your answer.

Comment: Try this. It’s toned down significantly. https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs164-09-spring/Handouts/handout19.pdf.  Or just Google blossoming.

Comment: It’s covered in many of the CAGD textbooks. Like the ones by Farin or Gallier.

Comment: Hi, Great. I've gone through the texts, but I still don't get how that intersection point of tangent things comes about, could you show a reference for it?

Comment: Well, on a quadratic curve, the polar values $F(u,u)$, $F(u,v)$ and $F(v,v)$ are the Bezier control points of the portion of the curve that lies between parameter values $u$ and $v$. Similar statements apply to curves of other degrees. And, for a quadratic curve, the middle control point is the intersection of the end tangents.

Comment: If you ask a question that includes the word “Bezier”,  I’ll find it after a few days, and I’ll try to answer it.